# How do I create a self-signed S/MIME signing certificate with OpenSSL and then sign a file?

Tags: openssl

I would like to create a certificate with OpenSSL and then use it to create an S/MIME format detached signature of a file. Is this something that makes sense in the context of S/MIME? How do I get OpenSSL to perform this task?